# How to create an array (or one long string) of hyperlinks in google docs using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-docs

Or how hyperlink of google docs looks like in raw format.

I tried to do the next thing:

```
var links;
var nameArr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
var tempArr= ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"];
for (i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
  nameArr[i].setUrlLink("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + tempArr[i] + "/detection"
  links = links + ", "+ nameArr[i];
}
```

I get an error, as i can't use setLinkUrl on string, only on text object - didn't find a way to cast string into text.

Although, if i paste it "as it", the "http..." shows as a regular string - not a link.

I Want to get something like this: 
[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13) ...... and paste it into google docs document.

Comment: And what happened with your current script and input? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging

Comment: What is setUrlLink?  I'm not aware of a method Array.setUrlLink().  If you are talking about the DocumentApp.Text.setLinkUrl(url) then the values in nameArr must be of class Text and I belive you would need to capture the return value such as nameArr[i] = nameArr[i].setLinkUrl(url) an then put it back into the body.

Comment: nameArr is an array of strings, how i can cast them into text ?

Comment: @Mark Waitzman Although I'm not sure whether I could understand what you want to do, if you want to replace the value of ``nameArr`` to the created URL, please modify ``nameArr[i].setUrlLink(...`` to ``nameArr[i] = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + tempArr[i] + "/detection"``. By the way, in your snippet, because ``links`` is not defined, an error occurs at ``links = links + ", "+ nameArr[i]``. And your for loop starts from 1. In this case, ``2`` of ``nameArr`` and ``12`` of ``tempArr`` are the start value. If this is what you want, it is not required to modify this.

Comment: @Tanaike I wrote this code as an example, the real code is much more complex - didn't want to confuse people with irrelevant code. But you understood right, the only thing is that i want nameArr[i] to be a hyperlink : Link "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + tempArr[i] , with name of nameArr[i]. Look at the example output i wrote.

Comment: @Mark Waitzman Thank you for replying. Where can I see the example output?

Comment: @Tanaike Last line of my post: The hyperlinks...

Comment: @Mark Waitzman I'm sorry I couldn't notice about ``https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11``. In this case, if my understanding of ``i want nameArr[i] to be a hyperlink`` is correct, you can use ``nameArr[i] = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + tempArr[i]``. By the way, in your snippet, because ``links`` is not defined, an error occurs at ``links = links + ", "+ nameArr[i]``.

Comment: @Tanaike Thats not what i want. You suggest output will be : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11
While i want to get [11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11)

Comment: @Mark Waitzman Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: @TheWizEd , can you give an example? How i can capture it as text and then put back?

Comment: I believe the answer below shows how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links are "rich" features of the associated element (usually [`Text`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text)). So to add a link to generic text, first you must get the associated `Text` element, and then invoke [`setLinkUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setLinkUrl(Integer,Integer,String)) on it.

As with other rich format methods, appended elements inherit the formatting specification of the preceding sibling element. Thus, if you format the last element of a parent, the next element appended to the parent will likely also be formatted in that manner. I explicitly specify a `nullstring` URL for the separator text to avoid the link extending beyond the actual display text. *(This means that if you programmatically append to the `Paragraph` after calling this function, that appended text will have the same URL as the last display text from your array.)*

This simple function takes a `Paragraph` as input, along with the array of display text and the URIs, and adds them to the end.

```
/**
 * Create links at the end of the given paragraph with the given text and the given urls.
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph} pg The paragraph to hold the link array
 * @param {string[]} values The display text associated with the given links
 * @param {string[]} links The URI for the given link text
 * @param {string} [separator] text that should separate the given links. Default is comma + space, `", "`
 * @returns {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph} the input paragraph, for chaining
 */
function appendLinkArray(pg, values, links, separator) {
  if (!pg || !values || !links)
    return;
  if (!values.length || !links.length || values.length > links.length)
    throw new Error("Bad input arguments");
  if (separator === undefined)
    separator = ", ";

  // Add a space before the link array if there isn't one at the end of any existing text.
  if (pg.getText() && (!pg.getText().match(/ $/) || !pg.getText().match(/ $/).length))
    pg.appendText(" ").setLinkUrl("");
  // Add each link display text as a new `Text` object, and set its link url.
  links.forEach(function (url, i) {
    var text = values[i] || url;
    pg.appendText(text)
      .setLinkUrl(0, text.length - 1, url);
    if (separator && i < links.length - 1)
      pg.appendText(separator).setLinkUrl("");
  });
  return pg;
}
```

Comment: I must use a paragraph to hold the links array?

Comment: @mark My example here uses a `Paragraph` as the destination for the end result. This is not a strict requirement. The point was to demonstrate how one creates a sequence of arbitrary characters that represents a hyperlink with the Google Docs Service. This example function works with anything that supports the `getText` and `appendText` methods.